# How to allow a specific IP address to read and write in the Firebase database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to Firebase and I am trying to allow read and write to the database from a specific IP addres without authentication. Is that even possible? Here are my database rulles:

```
{
```

"rules": {

```
".read": "ip_address === 'xx.xx.xxx.xx'",
".write": "ip_address === 'xx.xx.xxx.xx'",

"User": {

  "$uid": {
    "Something" : {
      ".read": "auth != null"
    },
    "SomethingElse" : {
      ".read": "auth != null"
    }

  }

}
```

}
}
But there isn't variable 'ip_address'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no security rules for restricting access based on IP address.  What you're trying to do is not possible.

Comment: I couldnt find anything like this myself, but I had to ask at least.